# Find closest value without going over

Tags: excel

I've found similar questions, but they're all at least slightly different from my question, and have been unable to successfully adapt them, so here's a simplified version of my sheet:

```
A     B     C     D     E
1     4     4     17
2     6     10
3     2     12
4     7     19
5     4     23
```

Column A is full of the integers 1-X. Column B is number of occurrences of Column A, and C is the sum of the values to the left and above. D is a random value between 1 and C5. So far so good. The problem comes with E1. I want it to give the value of A that is to the left of the C value that is the closest to D without going over.

Example: D comes up with the value 17. The closest value to 17 without going over is 12 (C3). Therefore, E equals 3. How would I go about achieving this? I can get the closest value using `=INDEX(A$1:A$5,MATCH(MIN(ABS(F1-C$1:C$5)),ABS(F1-C$1:C$5),0))`, but it comes to 4, instead of 3. How would I get the closest SMALL value? I'm guessing I have to replace ABS with SMALL, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A6,IFERROR(MATCH(D2,C2:C6,0)-1,MATCH(D2,C2:C6))),"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "vector form" of `LOOKUP` for this (see help for `LOOKUP` function). If you lookup `D1` in `C1:C5` you'll get exactly the match you want (the largest value that's smaller than or equal to `D1`) and then you can define the return vector as `A1:A5` to get the corresponding value from there

`=LOOKUP(D1,C$1:C$5,A$1:A$5)`

Note: You'll get an error for D1 values < 4 because in that case there's no value "without going over".

For this to work `C1:C5` must be sorted ascending, but that will always be the case in this scenario

Edit: I believe this answers your question, as stated, but if you were looking for the 17th occurrence, in order then shouldn't the result be 4? If that was the case then I think you could still use `LOOKUP` but column C would have to be set up differently

Comment: Oh, oops, your edit is correct. That's what I get for trying to do this sort of thing really late. Looks like I wanted the largest value then, not the smallest. Thanks to your comment, I did some searching, and wound up with `=INDEX(A$1:A$5,MATCH(D1,$C$1:$C$5,-1))`, and it gives the desired result (after re-ordering the columns into descending order). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In E1: `=if(C1<=D$1,A1,"")` and fill down.

In F1: `=max(E1:E5)`. This is your desired result.